# can I say "I hope you find this email well" as a greeting?

Tags: email, greetings

I heard that we can use "Hope this email finds you well."... But, can I say "I hope you find this email well" as a greeting? I know it has a different meaning, but still, can I say it?

Comment: No. Saying that means that you hope that they find the email itself well.

Comment: What do you mean by it? Do you hope that the email is well (healthy)? Do you hope they were able to find the email without much effort?

Comment: I'm leaving this question open because it's not a request for proofreading. It's asking about "something in particular", as the close reason suggests it should.

Answer (score 1):

No. While 'secondary predication' constructions are well known

- *He drove the car drunk* (depictive; subject-orientated)
- *He ate the prawns raw* (depictive; object-orientated) (plus resultative examples),

there are semantic restrictions on allowable examples. Thus

- **He drove the car infected*
- **He drove the car blue* [before it was resprayed in red]

are unidiomatic.

.........................

- *We found Helen well when we visited her*

is fine if a little dated.

- *Hoping this card/email ... finds you well*

is quirky but idiomatic.

But

- *I hope you find this card/email ... well*

is not an acceptable subject-orientated example.

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't seen this phrase, and I write/receive a ton of emails per day. I recommend sticking with "I hope this email finds you well." It rolls off the tongue better, plus the other phrase sounds a bit off.